# Launching an instance in a clustered placement group (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to launch an instance in a cluster placement group called "clustergroup"

[image]

However , when trying to spawn the instance in the group ,it doesn't appear in the list

[image]

I've tried to change the ami to be launched but it's the same situation

Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't far from the answer. It was the instance type that had to be be changed.
I had to choose a memory optimized instace for the full list of groups to appear.

According to the documentation , there are rules for using clustered groups -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html#concepts-placement-groups